# Diagonal formatting of grid / table

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting, grid-layouts

I have a table given by (a simple example for clarity)

```
Grid[
 MapThread[
  Prepend, {Prepend[
   Table[1, {m, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}], {"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}], {"Table", "m=0", "1", "2", "3", "4",
   "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}}],
 Frame -> {{True}, {True}}]/. 1 -> Style[1, Bold, Red]
```

It's just a grid of `1`s with all `1` highlighted in red. But what I want to know is how do I:

1. Create a downwards-diagonal line across the grid at `x=m`?
2. Turn the font style to grey for all items above that line, thus over-riding the `Bold, Red` instruction (not for values *on* the line, for values *above* it - i.e., for all `x>m`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, can I then label that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does some of what you request.  `Style` can be applied at quite low levels of the expression

```
Grid[MapThread[
  Prepend, {Prepend[
    Table[If[m >= x, Style[1, {Red, Bold}], Style[1, Gray]], {m, 0, 
      10}, {x, 0, 10}], {"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
     "8", "9", "10"}], {"Table", "m=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "10"}}], Frame -> {{True}, {True}}]
```

[image]

I don't know how you'd add diagonal lines.